# Does a LDAP library exist for JME?

Tags: ldap, java-me

I would like to know if a LDAP library exists for JME. Does anyone know ?

Best regards,
Quentin

Answer (score 1):

The Lightweight Directory Access Protocol uses TCP/IP.

MIDlets running on actual mobile phones in the field usually don't rely on simple TCP/IP connections because Mobile Network Operators have a tendancy to block all non-HTTP network traffic.

Even if a JavaME library existed, widespread deployment would be an issue.